# Click input on page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three  radio buttons and I want, by default, to have the "BOTH" location which has a value of 3 to be clicked on page load so that it will run my jQuery post function. The radio button is filled-in giving the appearance of being clicked, but the click is not happening to post my function. Once I change the radio button however, the code works fine.

This is my code:

```
$("input:radio[name='location'][value='3']").click();

$('input[name="location"]').change(function() {
    var location = $('input[name="location"]:checked').val(); var category = getUrlVars()["category"];
    $.post(
        'db/functions/package_conf.php',
        {category:category, location:location},
        function(data) {
            $('#package_info').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try to register the event handle first before trigger the event? `$("input:radio[name='location'][value='3']").click();` after the `.change'` event..
you may consider use the `checked` too, like $("input:radio[name='location'][value='3']").prop("checked", true).

but for my personally preference, any default state should be done before hand and not the in the script, for example initiate your radio DOM element to have `checked` property `<input type="radio" value="3" checked />`, and then onLoad script call the `post` directly (anyway POST is not designed for this purpose, just imagine POST as to save something, if you just want to get/query some data, GET would be more reasonable)

Comment: Woooooow! Worked, Its been bothering me for hours now and it was that simple!

Answer (score 1):

click was triggered before the change's event handler was regestered.

```
$('input[name="location"]').change(function() {
    var location = $('input[name="location"]:checked').val(); var category = getUrlVars()["category"];
    $.post(
        'db/functions/package_conf.php',
        {category:category, location:location},
        function(data) {
            $('#package_info').html(data);
    });
});

$("input:radio[name='location'][value='3']").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', (e) => {  $("#test").focus()  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" value="23" type="number" style="font-size:30px;width:150px;">
```